# simple jquery to load external content from div problem

Tags: jquery

I found and tried to change a short bit of jquery code to load external content into an existing div that I can't get to work. The problem I'm having is trying to make the code more usable since I have many links on the page. I'm a novice so I'm trying to see if I could keep it simple and I don't know where the problem is. The bit of code I am trying to modify:

```
$(function() {
  $('div[class="subNav"]').click(function() {
    $('#mainText').load$(this).attr('href'); 
       return false;
    });
});
```

mainPage.html has a div that wraps the main text of the page.

> ```
> <div id="mainText">Content Change Here</div>
> ```

I have multiple sub links (using an accordion menu & javascript) on this page under a different div.

```
<div class="subNav">

    <h3 class="heading">heading1</h3>
    <ul class="navListings">
      <li><a href="sub1a.html">link 1a</a></li>
      <li><a href="sub1b.html">link 1b</a></li>
      <li><a href="sub1c.html">link 1c</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h3 class="heading">heading2</h3>
    <ul class="navListings">
      <li><a href="sub2a.html">link 2a</a></li>
      <li><a href="sub2b.html">link 2b</a></li>
    </ul>

    ....and so on......</div>
```

All pages have the same mainText div for content. I just want to replace the mainText div on mainPage.html with the correct content from the sub-pages on click. Can someone help me? I'm guessing my code is a bit too simple....

I've tried many alternatives to the second line of code, but nothing works. I either get nothing to show up or the link just goes to page as if the script isn't even working. Thanks in advance to anyone that might be able to help...

Comment: Consider using Firefox and Firebug, if you are not already. Console errors and console.log() will help out much. http://www.alistapart.com/

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
$('div.subNav').click(function() {
$('#mainText').load($(this).attr('href')); 
   return false;
});
```

Remember to wrap this in a document.ready function

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $('div[class="subNav"]').click(function() {
    // missing `(` after load. as well as everything else.
    $('#mainText').load$(this).attr('href'); 
       return false;
    });
});
```

What are you trying to achieve with `.load` ?

```
$("#mainText").load("url", function() {
    // what are you doing here?
    $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

This should work though for that:

```
$(function() {
    $('div[class="subNav"]').click(function() {
        $('#mainText').load($(this).attr('href')); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm trying to figure it out as I go with the coding part. Pretty bad. I am only trying to load external content (from a different html page) into a specific div on the active page depending on the link that the user chooses. Would like to get the script to extract content (div id=mainText) from the corresponding page that the link points to and load that content into the active page's div.

Comment: that's my problem, unless I am understanding all of this incorrectly. I don't want to enter a specific url. I'm hoping the script will know to pull the url from the href link on the page. So if the visitor clicks on link 1b, the script will pull content from the mainText div in sub1b.html and replace the mainText div on mainPage.html.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated. I am having the same problem. The latest code you suggested doesn't do anything. Using the same example, when I click on link 1b, it loads sub1b.html instead of just loading the mainText content part. The issue for me is that sub1b.html and mainPage.html uses different templates and look different. I only want to extract the mainText div content into the page, not load the page. I don't think I need to add anything to the html part...